# What is the impact of adding a layer in neural networks?

Tags: neural-network, overfitting

I was playing with hyper-parameters on https://playground.tensorflow.org/ using spiral dataset (classification). So , first I trained a network with 2 hidden layers and the final test and train loss were around 0.02. After that , I introduced an extra layer (keeping everything other than that same) and trained it . To my surprise , the test loss was around 0.43 and train loss was around 0.37. I expected the test loss to increase , as the model was overfitting , however the significant increase in train loss was kind of counter-intuitive to me.

I am a newbie in this field and from what I know , adding a layer increases the model complexity so increase in test loss was expected but I also expected the train loss to be approximately same (or even decrease) as the model would overfit on train data. But the results show that model not only failed to generalise but even failed to fit on the training data.

I know that there can be many factors behind this , but can anyone please explain what could be the possible reason ?

Comment: It sounds to me like you made a much more complicated loss function to minimize and need more time to train it. What I would like to see addressed in an answer, though, is if the simpler model is nested into the complex model the way that it would be if your complex model had a wider hidden layer instead of an additional hidden layer, as the additional parameters in a wider hidden layer could be zero to give the simple model.

Comment: @Dave Actually the model converged in about 200 epochs , I trained it further for 1k epochs (reducing the step size) but the losses never changed. Also I re-trained the model many times but results were nearly same.

Comment: Please share your code and output.